# Is there a way to get a sum of ulongs at database side with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that contains a member `coins`. This member is of type `ulong`. Here is the class definition:

```
[Table("UserContests")]
public class UserContest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContestId { get; set; }
    public Contest Contest { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    
    public ulong Coins { get; set; }
}
```

Today I was surprised when I tried to do a sum of coins that Entity Framework Core wasn't able to do it:

```
ulong coins = await dbContext.UserContests
    .Where(o => o.ContestId == contest.Id)
    .SumAsync(o => o.Coins);
```

I get the following error:

> Ambiguous invocation: System.Threading.Tasks.Task
> SumAsync(this System.Linq.IQueryable<MoneyAppBackend.Entities.UserContest>,
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MoneyAppBackend.Entities.UserContest,decimal>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken

I thought it was an EF Core compilation limitation but then I tried to do the sum locally but surprisingly it didn't work either.

It seems `Sum` doesn't support `ulong` type. I ended with something like this:

```
var userContests = await dbContext.UserContests
    .Where(o => o.ContestId == contest.Id)
    .ToListAsync();
ulong coins = userContests.Select(o => o.Coins).Aggregate((a, c) => a + c);
```

Is it possible to do this at database side?

Comment: Please show the exact type of `Coins`, preferrably through a class definition. You claim it is `ulong` but the error seems to say it's `decimal` or maybe even `decimal?`, and we need to be sure.

Comment: I have just added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no overload for `SumAsync` that supports `ulong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.sumasync), and then it uses the `decimal` overload instead, or perhaps it can't decide between that overload and another one.

To fix this you can force a supported type yourself, e.g:

```
decimal coins = await dbContext.UserContests
    .Where(o => o.ContestId == contest.Id)
    .SumAsync(o => (decimal)o.Coins);
```

You can of course cast the end result back to `ulong` if you want.

Another alternative could be to use `Int64` instead of `ulong` in the Entity class, but it will give a smaller range of allowed positive numbers along with allowing negative numbers.

Comment: I was so focused that I forgot to cast to decimal :). Thanks for that!